# how to extract all css declarations that match a criteria into another css file

Tags: css, automation, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have a very specific situation that should be common to a lot of programmers but I can't find an automated general solution. The problem is the following:

I have a theme that includes some .css files with colors associated to the theme.

I want to create a "child theme" which means that I should overwrite just the necessary pieces so I want to create a .css file that, included after the main css file changes all the colors.

I don't want to modify the original css file nor I want to copy all the contents of the original css file into mine so what I would like to do is copy all the css declarations that have a property that changes the color.

So I've if the original file is like this:

**parent.css**

```
body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}

p {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

and so on and so on

I want to get

**child.css**

```
body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

a {
    color: red;
}
```

I assume this is no easy task as the solution would need to be able to detect color declarations as different as:

```
color: red;

border: 1px solid rgb(125,189,16);

font-color: #345
```

and many more.

But it's a common problem that I can't believe no one has, at least started, writing a solution for.

Does any of you know of an automated solution for something like that? even if it's a partial one?

Also I know the question is maybe a bit broad for stackoverflow and it does not directly involve a coding problem but I think this is the stack exchange forum more suited for it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1) The color mapping stuff seems like it is just annoying; all those names map to specific color values that can be compared.  2) Sure its a coding problem; you "just" have to code a CSS analyzer that will extract this information.    3) The software world is full of requests for various code analyses that you can't get off the shelf; the solution IMHO is to be able to build such tools easily.  4) How partial a solution are you willing to discuss?  I can sketch an approach to do this using customizable tools that could read/analyze CSS.

Comment: I was sure it was complicated but I expected that, being so common, there would be something resembling a solution.
I've worked around this for now. Thanks!